# ASP.NET Dynamic page

Tags: c#, asp.net

When something is added in the database, the counter(label) in the page adds up 1 even without doing anything.
Sorry, I just can't get the right words to research.

Comment: Do you mean you want the server to tell the client (in some way) to update its display? Not just when the client cals the server. Then something like SignalR would allow that (without using client polling).

Comment: We can easily help you if you show your code to us to see the error.

Comment: You need to create an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/MCVE)

Answer (score 0):

Use Ajax Long polling, Websockets or Signal R.  The page label increment will get pushed through from the database change for all clients though. Use sqldepedency or a timer or a combination.